# What's wrong with qsort comparator?

Tags: c, qsort

So I've been doing my homework on C, and there was this task:
"An array of ints is given, write a function that sorts them in following way:
first, the even numbers in non-decreasing order,
second, the odd numbers in non-increasing".
For example, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] -> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1].

The task itself is about writing a comparator function for qsort correctly. I wrote the following `cmp`:

```
int
cmp(const void *elem1, const void *elem2)
{
    int p_number1 = *(int *) elem1, p_number2 = *(int *) elem2, diff_flag = 0;
    if (p_number1 > p_number2) {
        diff_flag = 1;
    } else if (p_number1 < p_number2) {
        diff_flag = -1;
    }
    if ((p_number1 & 1) == (p_number2 & 1)) { // same parity
        return diff_flag == 0 ? 0 : diff_flag ^ ((p_number1 & 1) << 31);
        /* in even case, diff_flag will be returned, otherwise,
         * number with sign that is different from diff_flag's will be returned */
    }
    return (p_number1 & 1) - (p_number2 & 1); // if first is odd, and second is even, 1 is returned, and vice versa
}
```

and the testing system spits out a runtime error. it does return INT_MIN and INT_MAX for less and bigger cases respectively, but doesn't that satisfy qsort's specifications? besides, it worked fine on all the arrays I was testing it with locally. Maybe anyone knows why is there a RE?

P.S.
I understand I'm making it in the most non-readable way possible, but I am obliged to rely mostly on bit ops and do everything in most optimal way possible, so I apologize for complexity.

Comment: start from moving parity comparisons at the top

Comment: @tstanisl, you mean, before calculating diff_flag? but it would break then

Comment: That means, the odd/even comparison should take priority, so deal with that first. Then if they have the same parity compare the magnitude. Don't even look at the magnitude until you've made the parity decision.

Comment: @WeatherVane, well, that certainly is a correct decision in regards to optimization, but I think that the reason behind RE lies elsewhere. am I wrong?

Comment: It's overly complicated. I don't get what the XOR and bit-shifting are for.

Comment: @WeatherVane because my teacher would reject my code if I wrote it like you did in your answer :) I agree that this is something like a sqrt from quake, but believe me, it's not like I want to write those things myself. on ASM level, it will perform less operations, so in my tasks, it is more preferable

Comment: Why would he reject it?  What other requirements were you given that you're not telling us?  Please add those requirements to the question.

Comment: @dbush did it in most detail I can. Unfortunately, my teacher is not very gregarious, and you can never know exactly what he'll accept or reject :)

Comment: anyhow, thank you for your help, gentlemen!

Comment: If you want to know why your teacher's peculiar code ideas crash, use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(p_number1 & 1) << 31` is *undefined behavior* (UB) when `p_number1 & 1` is non-zero.

Shifting a 1 into the sign bit is UB.  Even if it is unfortunately taught as some way to perform bit manipulations and/or works on OP's machine, it remains UB and should be avoided.

It is also UB when `int` is 16-bit as shifting the width or more is UB.

A runtime error is one form of UB.

---

Alternative

```
int
cmp(const void *elem1, const void *elem2)
{
    int p_number1 = *(const int *) elem1; // Better form to not cast away const
    int p_number2 = *(const int *) elem2;
    if ((p_number1 ^ p_number2) & 1)) { // never UB with 2's complement
      return (p_number1 & 1) - (p_number2 & 1); 
    }
    // Only compare values when the same "parity".
    int diff_flag = (p_number1 > p_number2) - (p_number1 < p_number2);
    if (p_number1 & 1) {
      diff_flag = -diff_flag;
    }
    return diff_flag;
}
```

Comment: thank you, that is indeed my mistake. I think a cast should fix it then.

Comment: @nikita Casting can readily incur other negative issues, best avoided for learners.  Rather than tricky code, code for clarity.  Clear code is easier for compilers to optimize and emits better code than employing tricks to outdo a compiler.  Save your valuable time for [larger issues](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/94903).  Such weak programming practices as being promoted by the prof are of dubious value.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to aim for readable, understandable code, rather than relying on knowledge of the bit patterns of ints, and using XOR and shifts.

Something like:

```c
int cmp(const void *elem1, const void *elem2)
{
    int number1 = *(int *) elem1;
    int number2 = *(int *) elem2;
    int odd1 = number1 & 1;
    int odd2 = number2 & 1;
    int rv;

    // Special case for equal, to simplify the ternary expressions below
    if (number1 == number2)
        return 0;

    if (odd1) {
        if (odd2)
            rv = number2 > number1 ? 1 : -1;
        else
            rv = 1;
    } else {
        if (!odd2)
            rv = number1 > number2 ? 1 : -1;
        else
            rv = -1;
    }
    return rv;
}
```

This will also work on different sized ints, rather than relying on 32-bit ints.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the parity first, as in this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *elem1, const void *elem2)
{
    int a = *(int *) elem1;
    int b = *(int *) elem2;
    
    // compare the parity
    int diff = (a & 1) - (b & 1);
    if(diff)
        return diff;
        
    // compare the magnitude
    if((a & 1) == 0)
        return (a > b) - (a < b);
    else 
        return (b > a) - (b < a);
}


int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int len = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];
    qsort(arr, len, sizeof arr[0], cmp);
    
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
2 4 6 8 10 9 7 5 3 1
```

Comment: I agree that it is much more simple and understandable. However, my teacher thinks otherwise and will not accept something like you wrote (by the way, comparison through subtraction may lead to overflow). Thank you very much for your answer, but I cannot change the general look of the code - I only need to know what may be causing the RE.

Comment: I agree with a part of that: I've changed the comparison to avoid potentional overflow.

Comment: I'm afraid `a & 1 - b & 1` is parsed as `a & (1 - b) & 1`; probably not what you expect

Comment: @chqrlie oops... thanks. it somehow didn't prevent the right output though.

Comment: Little reasons\ for `int len`.  Better as `size_t len` and avoid 2 type changes.